# Select all objects in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have three objects:

> Artist, Albums and Track.

The artists are stored in a `List<Artist>` and inside the Artist object there's another list for the artist's Albums (`List<Albums>`) And in the Album object there is yet another list for the tracks (`List<Track>`)

How would you go about selecting all the tracks at once?

Is there any way to do:

```
TrackList.AddRange(ArtistList.Albums.Tracks);
```

Until now I have been doing this:

```
foreach (Artist artist in artistlist)
  {
     if (artist.Albums != null)
     {
       ForEach(Album album in artist.Albums)
       {
         Context.AddRange(album.Tracks);
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Use SelectMany (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640415/selectmany-three-levels-deep)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
TrackList.AddRange(
  ArtistList.SelectMany(a => a.Albums)
            .SelectMany(a => a.Tracks))
```

Or something to that effect. I'm a little rusty on `SelectMany`, but I'm fairly confident it can be used here.

I'm also 
not sure whether your `null` check is needed here, too. But you can add a `Where` clause before the `SelectMany`.

Comment: The thing is; the null check does have to be there.. But I can fix that where I initialize the lists. So this solution will work after some, work.. Haha thank you so much :)

Comment: Well, in that case `ArtistList.Where(a => a.Albums != null).SelectMany ...` should work.

Comment: Yeah I guess. But the job is already done ;) Just had to write one line of code where the albums gets added. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`.